# git-svn clone with multiple repositories to multiple branches in local machine

Tags: git, svn, git-svn, git-clone

I have a svn remote repo as follows:

```
SW
    branches
        A
        B
        C
    tags

    trunk
```

Initially I was working on Branch A, so I treat it as a repository and use the following command to get it on my local machine

```
git svn clone --no-minimize-url rHEAD /path/to/svn-server/branches/A
```

so my local repository will be like this:

```
A [Folder]
    master       [branch]
    my_devlop    [branch]
```

But now I also have to work on branch C, I need to merge some of my code in my_devlop to branch C.

So I use the following command to get all of the branches under SW:

```
git svn clone --no-minimize-url rHEAD /path/to/svn-server/branches
```

However, this will treat each branch as a single repository under branches.

Like the following in my local machine

```
branches [folder]
    A    [folder]
    B    [folder]
    C    [folder]
```

But what I want is the following

```
branches [folder]
    A [branch]
    B [branch]
    C [branch]
```

So that I can merge each branch in my local machine.
Is this possible? Or my workflow has some mistake?

Any tips will be appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably do the following:

```
git svn clone --no-minimize-url rHEAD --stdlayout /path/to/svn-server
```

The option `--stdlayout` will give you a git repository with a branch for the SVN trunk and for each SVN branch.

Comment: I have tried that command, however I get the error that E: 'trunk' is not a complete URL and a separate URL is not specified.

Comment: Does your SVN repository actually have a `trunk` folder? If not, you need to avoid `--stdlayout` and use the `--branches` and `--tags` option as explained in the man page of git-svn.